# Cannot find any scalar summaries in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am doing mnist tutorial, and fully_connected_feed.py works and saves events.out.tfevents.1447186888 file to ~..\data\
when I trying to open TensorBoard like this

```
python ~/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py --logdir=~/tensorflow/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/data
```

or like this

```
tensorboard --logdir=~/tensorflow/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/data
```

It opens, but then I see  "No scalar summary tags were found."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use

`tensorboard --logdir=home/$USER/tensorflow/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/data`

or

`tensorboard --logdir=${PWD}`    in that directory

Because tensorboard checks path existence by using os.path.exists()

=

Regarding that, I would like to set `alias tensorboard='tensorboard --logdir=${PWD}'`  for convenient

Comment: Great idea with the alias, very useful!